# program which takes two strings as input from the user (str1 and str2)

Tags: python, string

Write a program that takes two strings as input from the user (str1 and str2) and prints two strings as output (op1 and op2).

- op1 should contain all the characters which are present in str1 but NOT present in str2.
- op2 should contain all the characters which are present in str2 but NOT present in str1.

For example:

str1
str2
op1
op2

Example 1

ABC
BC
A
`<null>`

Example 2

BC
BANGALORE
C
ANGLORE

Comment: What language are you using? Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Not sure if this is a question or a challenge

Comment: it's a question asked in interview, I'm unable to understand what is this so posted here for a help

Comment: And It's a python language..

Comment: Please include have you tried in your question. And, read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class HelloWorld
{

    public Tuple<string, string> StringOutput(string str1, string str2)
    {
        string output1 = "";
        string output2 = "";

        HashSet<char> record = new HashSet<char>();
        for (int i = 0; i < str2.Length; ++i)
        {
            record.Add(str2[i]);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < str1.Length; ++i)
        {
            if (!record.Contains(str1[i]))
            {
                output1 = output1 + str1[i];
            }
        }

        HashSet<char> data = new HashSet<char>();
        for (int i = 0; i < str1.Length; ++i)
        {
            data.Add(str1[i]);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < str2.Length; ++i)
        {
            if (!data.Contains(str2[i]))
            {
                output2 = output2 + str2[i];
            }
        }


        return new Tuple<string, string>(output1, output2);
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        HelloWorld task = new HelloWorld();
        Console.Write("Enter Input1: ");
        string input1 = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Enter Input2: ");
        string input2 = Console.ReadLine();

        var result = task.StringOutput(input1, input2);

        string output1 = result.Item1 == "" ? "<null> " : result.Item1;
        string output2 = result.Item2 == "" ? "<null> " : result.Item2;

        Console.Write("Op1 = " + output1 + " Op2 = " + output2);
    }

}
```

Comment: Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].

Answer (score 0):

In Golang You can do as :

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
"strings"
 )

func main() {
var str1, str2 string

fmt.Println("enter string 1")
fmt.Scan(&str1)
fmt.Println("enter string 2")
fmt.Scan(&str2)

op1 := strings.Trim(str1, str2)
fmt.Println(op1)
op2 := strings.Trim(str2, str1)
fmt.Println(op2)
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).